# parsing for nested table using xstream

Tags: xml, xstream

I am try to parse the below xml using xstream with the below code. But i keep getting parse execeptions.

```
<result xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='/getIpTable/getIpTable.xsd'>
        <IPAddressInfo>
            <ipAddrEntry>
                <ipAdEntIfIndex>607</ipAdEntIfIndex>
                <ipAdEntAddr>172.23.218.126</ipAdEntAddr>
                <ipAdEntNetMask>255.255.255.192</ipAdEntNetMask>
            </ipAddrEntry>
        </IPAddressInfo>
    </result>



XStream xStream = new XStream();
         xStream.alias("result", IPAddressInfo.class);
         xStream.alias("ipAddrEntry", Entry.class);
         xStream.alias("ipAdEntIfIndex", String.class);
         xStream.alias("ipAdEntAddr", String.class);
         xStream.alias("ipAdEntNetMask", String.class);
        IPAddressInfo ipAddressInfo = new IPAddressInfo();
        ipAddressInfo=(IPAddressInfo) xStream.fromXML(xml);
        System.out.println("------"+ipAddressInfo);
```

## Classes:

```
public class IPAddressInfo implements java.io.Serializable, InfoIf {
    public IPAddressEntry[] ipAddresses;

    public String name() { return "IPAddressInfo"; };

    public String toString() {
        String rc = new String("IPAddressInfo collected:\n");
        for (int i = 0; ipAddresses != null && i < ipAddresses.length; i++) {
            rc += "  entry" + i + "------------------------------------\n";
            rc += "    ifIndex = " + ipAddresses[i].ifIndex + "\n";
            rc += "    IP      = " + ipAddresses[i].ip.getHostAddress() + "\n";
            rc += "    ipMask  = " + ipAddresses[i].ipMask.getHostAddress() + "\n";
        }
        return rc;
    }
}
```

## IPAddressEntry class :

```
public class IPAddressEntry implements java.io.Serializable {
    public int ifIndex;
    public InetAddress ip;
    public InetAddress ipMask;
}
```

Below are the class details used in the client class.

## InfoIf class:

```
public interface InfoIf {

    public String name();

     public String toString();
}
```

Comment: Where is `ipAddresses` initialized? I can see it being declared and used, but can't see anything its values are populated.

Comment: IPAddressEntry represents the ipAddresses

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved with below code.

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
        xstream.alias("ipAddressInfo", IPAddressInfo.class);
        xstream.alias("ipAddrEntry", IPAddressEntry.class);
        xstream.addImplicitCollection(IPAddressInfo.class, "ipAddresses");
```